# How can I reshape my test data in Sklearn? (feature selection)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have two datasets, one for training and the other for testing:

- Training data has `X_train.shape = (5000, 30)` and `y_train.shape = (5000, 1)`
- Testing data only has `X_test.shape = (5000, 30)`

In the training one, I apply feature selection (`SelectKBest()`), resulting to a new shape `(5000, 10)`.

The problem begins with the testing data: there is no output, therefore I can not apply `SelectKBest()` because it needs `y_test`. How can I reshape test data, given the new shape and new features of my training data?

Comment: As with any sklearn transformer, `fit()` it to the training data, and use it to `transform()` the training and the test data

Comment: or go with `Pipeline`

Comment: @G.Anderson  @Shibab  Can I use `get_support(True)` to get index values of my features and then create `X_new_test` with all that index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to overthink sklearn transformers. In the comments you asked

> Can I use get_support(True) to get index values...

That's too much work!
Try

```
best=SelectKBest(*args).fit(X_train,y_train)
new_train=best.transform(X_train)
new_test=best.transform(X_test)
```

the same way you would with a tfidftransformer or a standardscaler